# What do you call a fully connected directed graph where each node has at most one outbound edge?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, directed-graph

A fully connected directed graph where each node has at most a one inbound edge is a tree. Does a fully connected directed graph where each node has at most a single outbound edge have a name? Anti-tree?!

Comment: ["Anti-Arborescence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)) is such mouthful... Is "in-tree" the best we can do?

Comment: No answers yet, care to write one as you've found the answer?

Comment: In a cycle also each node has at most one incoming (and outgoing) edge. A cycle is not a tree.

Comment: Ah, right, I should have also added a-cyclic. Still cool that they have a name for the graph I described. In fact, it always has exactly one cycle!

Comment: @ChristopherKing fair enough! You may also want to be careful with phrasing - in graph theory, a graph can be "connected" or "complete", which are different properties. In other fields, "fully connected" is taken to mean complete. I've assumed that by "fully connected" you mean just "connected", as complete wouldn't make any sense here, but it's something to bear in mind in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this does indeed have a name - it is a **directed pseudotree**.

From the [Wikipedia article on pseudoforests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoforest):

> A directed pseudoforest is a directed graph in which each vertex has
>   at most one outgoing edge; that is, it has outdegree at most one. A
>   directed 1-forest – most commonly called a functional graph, sometimes maximal directed pseudoforest – is a directed graph
>   in which each vertex has outdegree exactly one.[8] If D is a directed
>   pseudoforest, the undirected graph formed by removing the direction
>   from each edge of D is an undirected pseudoforest.

Hence, we can call the graph you describe above a **directed pseudoforest**. You also note that the graph is connected. From the same page:

> A pseudotree is a connected pseudoforest.

Hence, the term **directed pseudotree**.

Here is the proper definition of an undirected pseudoforest, for your information, from [Wolfram Alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pseudoforest.html):

> A pseudoforest is an undirected graph in which every connected
>   component contains at most one graph cycle. A pseudotree is therefore
>   a connected pseudoforest and a forest (i.e., not-necessarily-connected
>   acyclic graph) is a trivial pseudoforest.
>
> Some care is needed when encountering pseudoforests as some authors
>   use the term to mean "a pseudoforest that is not a forest."